# How to determine band-pass frequency and bandwidth in photodiode TIA circuit

Tags: photodiode, bandwidth, passive-filter, band-pass, transimpedance-amplifier

I'm trying to figure out how a photodiode amplifier circuit works. It is used in my university plasma physics lab to measure plasma density through laser interferometry.

This circuit was designed 20 years ago, and nobody involved in the design is around anymore. My end goal is to redesign the circuit to reduce noise and improve response time. Right now I need help figuring out the band-pass filter.

After the laser passes through our plasma, it hits the photodiode carrying a beat frequency of about 40 MHz, and this circuit is used to track the phase shift of that beat frequency over time, which lets us calculate how the plasma density changes over time.

The band pass filter is supposed to be centered around 40 MHz, with a 10 MHz bandwidth. I am unsure which components in the circuit contribute to that filter, and how to mathematically determine the center frequency and bandwidth based on the circuit components. I believe the filter consists of the components within the blue outline in the attached photo, but I'm not sure.

I'd really appreciate any help in understanding how this filter works, and how to preserve its function (or even narrow the bandwidth) while changing other components to improve noise and response time.

Annotations in blue, red, and green show my current understanding of the circuit. Information in black is everything I have from the previous design.

[image: Diagram of the photodiode amplifier circuit in question.]

Comment: Harry Furey-Soper - Hi, In order to comply with the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing), details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided next to that material. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then please [edit] the question & add its *name* & *link* (URL). If the original source was a printed book or other offline material, then [edit] the question & add a normal citation (see the linked rule for details). TY

Comment: Response time will be limited by your bandwidth, which it sounds like you can't change. What photodiode is that? 45v is a lot, maybe avalanche diode? Link a datasheet.

Comment: Narrowing the bandwidth will make the response slower. That's just the inverse relationship of time and frequency, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Harry, Phil Hobbs has a pretty good book on the general topic: "Building Electro-Optical Systems". Burr-Brown also has a number of papers to read. Though I cannot say they discuss the exact circuit front-end that you show there.

Comment: The easy way to answer your headline question is to just make a simulation model of the circuit. There is a SPICE model available for the AD603 but it's not clear exactly which SPICE variant the model is intended for. I expect the model predates ADI's acquisition of Linear Technologies and is meant for something other than LTSpice.